# cygwin getting invoked and end of stack error in bat file

Tags: batch-file, cygwin

I am running the following bat file and got an error

```
assertion "root_idx != -1" failed: 
file "/ext/build/netrel/src/cygwin-1.7.1-1/winsup/cygwin/mount.cc", 
line 363, function: void mount_info::init()
Stack trace: Some random stack trace
ENd of stack Trace
```

batch code

```
@echo off
:top
set /a run=1
echo "Beginning of Loop"
echo %run%
wmic process where "name like '%%java%%' and CommandLine like '%%abc%%'" get caption, CommandLine | findstr "abc" 1>nul || set /a run=0
if %run%==0 (
echo "Process Not Running"
start cmd /c 'path to file')
echo "Taking a Pause"
sleep 10
goto :top
```

Why is cygwin getting invoked in the first place?
and why did i get the error and the infinite loop halted (the loop checks for the existence of a program and starts it if it is killed somehow

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to avoid the Cygwin error but if you don't want it to be invoked, check your PATH variable so that the Cygwin path is not in it, or at least it is at the end of the path list.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Cygwin bug http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/cygwin-crash-assertion-quot-root-idx-1-quot-failed-reliably-reproduced-on-my-system-td2659.html.

In my case it started to reproduce after some build processes (and the Cygwin consoles associated with them) got into Suspended state. I saw it with the Process Explorer tool (the one from https://live.sysinternals.com/).

I don't know the cause why they were suspended. Perhaps the parent process was killed at the moment they waited for something. It does not really matter. But what does matter is that after that every new Cygwin console hanged when I opened it. The fix for me was *to find the old suspended Cygwin processes and kill them*.

> Why is cygwin getting invoked in the first place?

When you run something in the cmd.exe, but your PATH is configured to use Cygwin it tries to run your command in Cygwin first (depending on the order in the PATH).

> why did i get the error and the infinite loop halted

I suppose you had the same issue like me. That is every new Cygwin console hangs until you kill the first problematic one.